# passing value from searchTwitter with textInput value to get_nrc_sentiment

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I am planning to do a online Twitter sentiment analyzer that user can enter the search term by themselves using flexdashboard. Here is the code.

```
#Getting search term
textInput("data", label = "Enter search term", value = "", width = NULL, placeholder = NULL)
sliderInput("maxTweets", "Number of recent tweets to use for analysis:", min = 10, max = 1000, value = 500)
actionButton("enter", label = "Enter")

twt <- reactive({
  if(input$enter!=0){
      isolate({
        twt <- searchTwitter(input$data, n=input$maxTweets, lang = "en", resultType = "recent")
      })
    }
  })

#print tweets searched
twt
```

Here is the problem. When I run the code below, an error occurred "Error in get_nrc_sentiment: Data must be a character vector.". I have tried map_chr and as.character before but I don't have the column to select.

```
#Get sentiment 
s <- reactive({
  s<- get_nrc_sentiment(twt())
  })

#Print output
s
```

Comment: You&#39;re passing a data.frame or list to `get_nrc_sentiment`, instead of just the column of `text`. Try, `twt()$text` is it's a data frame.

Comment: It returns the same error when I tried `s <- get_nrc_sentiment(twt()$text)`

Comment: The `searchTwitter` function is from the deprecated `twitteR` package which returned a list, there is a function of that package called `twListToDF` which you must run to turn the results into a data.frame. however I would strongly advise using the `rtweet` package instead.

Comment: Although I changed my code to `twt <- reactive({
  if(input$enter!=0){
      isolate({
        twt <- search_tweets(input$data, n=input$maxTweets, lang = "en", resultType = "recent", include_rts = FALSE)
      })
    }
  })` the 's <- reactive({
  s<- get_nrc_sentiment(twt()$text)
  })` still return "Error in get_nrc_sentiment: Data must be a character vector.". I think this is caused by the self input or reactive function because when I ran the `srch <- search_tweets("#rstats", n = 1000)` it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment I would strongly advise moving to [rtweet](http://rtweet.info/), as stated on the `twitteR` [Github page](https://github.com/geoffjentry/twitteR):

> This is the start of a relatively leisurely deprecation period for twitteR, in favor of using rtweet. Please start looking to switch over to that package. If you have any questions contact myself or @mkearney

The last commit on that repository was 2 years ago.

If you want to use `twitteR` nonetheless.

```
twt <- searchTwitter(input$data, n=100, lang = "en", resultType = "recent")
twt <- twiListToDF(twt) # turn data.frame into a list
twt$text <- as.character(twt$text) # ensure it's a character vector

class(twt)
class(twt$text)

syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(txt$text)
```

You had to make sure it was 1) a vector 2) of type character

```
syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(as.factor(c("Hello", "World")))
#> Error in syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(as.factor(c("Hello", "World"))) : 
  Data must be a character vector.
syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(list("Hello", "World"))
#> Error in syuzhet::get_nrc_sentiment(list("Hello", "World")) : 
  Data must be a character vector.
```

Comment: `rtweet` returns a data.frame where `text` if of class `character`

Comment: Sorry to bother again. I have no idea why I use the rtweet in `twt <- reactive({
  if(input$enter!=0){
      isolate({
        twt <- search_tweets(input$data, n=100, lang = "en", include_rts = FALSE)
      })
    }
  })` the `s <- reactive({
  s<- get_nrc_sentiment(twt())
  })` still shows error with "Error in get_nrc_sentiment: Data must be a character vector."

Comment: You are using `runtime: shiny` correct? [doc](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/shiny.html) - `reactive` functions will not work otherwise.

Comment: Yes. Is that means there is no possible to do a self input function? Because now I am creating a sentiment analysis engine with self input function.

Comment: It will only work with `runtime: shiny`. Do you still encounter any issue/error?

Comment: At this phrase now is no more error. But for the `plain_tweets()` how to let it clean the tweets? I have noticed that this function only cleans up the URL with removing the https and www.

Comment: To clean tweets I suggest you look at other packages that specialise on text mining, i.e.:[tidytext](https://www.tidytextmining.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is my answer.

`````
```{r}
#Getting search term
textInput("data", label = "Enter search term", value = "")
actionButton("enter", label = "Enter")

twt <- reactive({
  if(input$enter!=0){
      isolate({
        return(search_tweets(input$data, n=100, lang = "en", include_rts = FALSE))
      })
    }
  })
```  

````{r}
#Get sentiment score of tweets
s <- reactive({
  return(get_nrc_sentiment(twt()$text))
  })
#Print sentiment score
renderTable(head(s()))
```
`````